# Monoid for compensated (Kahan) summation?

Tags: haskell, floating-point, sum, monoids

Suppose I have code like this, for performing compensated (Kahan-Babuška-Neumaier) summation of `Double`s:

```
-- A type for compensated summation.
data Sum = Sum {-# UNPACK #-} !Double {-# UNPACK #-} !Double
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

-- Add a number to the Sum, updating the error value as well.
addSum :: Sum -> Double -> Sum
addSum (Sum s c) x = Sum s' c' where
  s' = s + x
  d  | abs s >= abs x = (s - s') + x
     | otherwise      = (x - s') + s
  c' = c + d
{-# INLINE addSum #-}

-- Get the compensated value from the Sum.
getSum :: Sum -> Double
getSum (Sum s c) = s + c
{-# INLINE getSum #-}

-- Add a whole list (or list-like object) of Doubles.
sumAll :: Foldable f => f Double -> Double
sumAll ls = getSum $ foldl' addSum (Sum 0 0) ls
{-# INLINE sumAll #-}
```

However, I also have need for a `Monoid` for it, because I want to calculate values in parallel. What I'm looking for is something along the lines of:

```
-- Make a Sum from a Double value. It has an error of 0.
mkSum :: Double -> Sum
mkSum x = Sum x 0
{-# INLINE mkSum #-}

instance Monoid Sum where
  mempty = Sum 0 0
  {-# INLINE mempty #-}

  mappend (Sum sa ca) (Sum sb cb) = ...?
```

I'm thinking it might have a form resembling:

```
  mappend a@(Sum sa ca) b@(Sum sb cb)
    | ???       = addSum a (sb + cb)
    | otherwise = addSum b (sa + ca)
```

I want it to be commutative, and at least as associative as normal `Double` addition, if not more so.

Comment: This is not really about Haskell but about the Kahan summation itself, is it? Probably better asked at [CS.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) or [SciComp.SE](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

If there's a correct `mappend` it's probably

```
mappend :: Sum -> Sum -> Sum
mappend (Sum s c) (Sum x c2) = Sum s' c' where
  s' = s + x
  d  | abs s >= abs x = (s - s') + x
     | otherwise      = (x - s') + s
  c' = (c + c2) + d
```

Source: a hunch.

The hunch is it's the simplest thing that satisfies the property `mappend s1 (Sum x 0) = addSum s1 x` and is commutative. The associativity of it is very difficult to check.

It's difficult to check associativity because adding `Double`s isn't associative. Therefore `mappend` for `Sum` isn't associative; the question is, is it associative *enough*. A likely criteria is that the change in error from associating `mappend` is less than or equal to the change in error from commuting the arguments to `sumAll`.

For your criteria, it's already "at least as associative as normal `Double` addition", because it is normal `Double` addition. In fact, it's an improvement on normal `Double` addition. If `Double`s were associative then `d` would be `0`. Any non-zero `d` added to the sum `c1 + c2` is an *improvement* on the associativity of `Double` addition, tracking and correcting an error in the non-associativity of the `Double`s.

---

The calculation for `c'` can be improved by using a better method of summing `Double`s. They could be sorted, a la:

```
sumThree :: Double -> Double -> Double -> Double
sumThree a b c
    | abs a >= abs b && abs a >= abs c = (b + c) + a
    | abs b >= abs a && abs b >= abs c = (a + c) + b
    | otherwise                        = (a + b) + c
```

or summed using Kahan summation themselves, `sumAll [c, c2, d]`. If they're summed using Kahan summation themselves, `sumAll` can't be implemented in terms of `mappend`.